# How to perform counts on a Oracle Hierarchical Table based on Parent Link?

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle11g, tree

I have the following Oracle 11g R2 hierarchical table definition:

```
Table Name: TECH_VALUES:
    ID,
    GROUP_ID,
    LINK_ID
    PARENT_GROUP_ID,
    TECH_TYPE
```

Based on the above hierarchical table definition, some sample data might look like this:

```
ID      GROUP_ID      LINK_ID      PARENT_GROUP_ID      TECH_TYPE     
------- ------------- ------------ -------------------- --------------
1       100           LETTER_A     0
2       200           LETTER_B     0
3       300           LETTER_C     0
4       400           LETTER_A1    100                  A               
5       500           LETTER_A2    100                  A               
6       600           LETTER_A3    100                  A               
7       700           LETTER_AA1   400                  B              
8       800           LETTER_AAA1  700                  C             
9       900           LETTER_B2    200                  B               
10      1000          LETTER_BB5   900                  B              
12      1200          LETTER_CC1   300                  C
13      1300          LETTER_CC2   300                  C
14      1400          LETTER_CC3   300                  A
15      1500          LETTER_CCC5  1400                 A
16      1600          LETTER_CCC6  1500                 C
17      1700          LETTER_BBB8  900                  B
18      1800          LETTER_B     0
19      1900          LETTER_B2    1800                 B               
20      2000          LETTER_BB5   1900                 B              
21      2100          LETTER_BBB8  1900                 B
```

Keeping in mind that there are only three Tech Types, i.e. A, B and C but can span over over different `LINK_IDs`, how can I perform a count on these three different `TECH_TYPEs` based only on the parent link ids where the parent group id is 0 and there children below them?

### Updated note

It is also possible to have duplicate parent link ids, such as LETTER_B and all of the same children values but for different GROUP IDs.

I am basically after a table/report query that looks like this:

```
ID  Link ID        Tech Type A         Tech Type B          Tech Type C  Group ID
--- -------------- ------------------- -------------------- ------------ --------------
1   LETTER_A       3                   1                    1            100
2   LETTER_B       0                   3                    0            200
3   LETTER_C       2                   0                    3            300
4   LETTER_B       0                   3                    0            1800
```

Being hierarchical and that my table may consist of over 30,000 records, I need to also ensure that the performance to produce the above report query shown here is fast.

Obviously in order to produce the above report, I need to gather all necessary count breakdowns based on `TECH_TYPE` for all parent link id where the `PARENT_GROUP_ID = 0` and store these in a table as per this report layout .

How can I write a combined query that performs the counts as well as stores the information into a new table called LINK_COUNTS, which this report will be based off? Columns for this table will be:

```
ID,
LINK_ID,
TECH_TYPE_A,
TECH_TYPE_B,
TECH_TYPE_C,
GROUP_ID
```

In the end of this whole requirement, I want to be able to update the LINK_COUNTS table based on the results returned from the sample data above as part of just one SQL UPDATE transaction as the top level parent link ids will already exist within my LINK_COUNTS table, just need to provide count breakdown values for each parent node link, i.e.

```
LETTER_A     
LETTER_B     
LETTER_C
LETTER_B
```

using something like:

```
UPDATE link_counts
SET (TECH_TYPE_A,TECH_TYPE_B,TECH_TYPE_C) =
(with xyz

where link_id = LINK_COUNTS.link_id
....
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the data try this:

```
with xyz as (
    select tech_type,
        connect_by_root(link_id) as root_link_id,
        connect_by_root(group_id) as root_group_id
    from tech_values
    start with parent_group_id = 0
    connect by prior group_id = parent_group_id
)
select root_link_id, root_group_id,
    a_tech_type as tech_type_a, b_tech_type as tech_type_b, c_tech_type as tech_type_c
from xyz pivot (
        count(1) as tech_type
        for tech_type in (
            'A' as A,
            'B' as B,
            'C' as C
        ))
;
```

On a test set of 39000 records it took an Intel Core i5 with Oracle 11.2 (and flushed buffer cache) approx 0.15 sec to compute this. I hope it is quick enough to satisfy your needs.

To update the target table with these data, eithr loop through the above `SELECT` and update your `link_counts` table iteratively, or simply use the `MERGE` statement:

```
merge into link_counts T
using (
    with xyz as (
        select tech_type,
            connect_by_root(link_id) as root_link_id,
            connect_by_root(group_id) as root_group_id
        from tech_values X
        start with parent_group_id = 0
        connect by prior group_id = parent_group_id
    )
    select *
    from xyz pivot (
            count(1) as tech_type
            for tech_type in (
                'A' as A,
                'B' as B,
                'C' as C
            ))
) S
on ( T.group_id = S.root_group_id )
when matched then
    update
    set T.tech_type_a = S.a_tech_type,
        T.tech_type_b = S.b_tech_type,
        T.tech_type_c = S.c_tech_type
when not matched then
    insert (link_id, group_id, tech_type_a, tech_type_b, tech_type_c)
    values (S.root_link_id, S.root_group_id, S.a_tech_type, S.b_tech_type, S.c_tech_type)
;
```

The `MERGE` assumes that the `GROUP_ID` is a primary/unique key in the `link_counts` table. The actual definition of the `tech_values` table in the original question supports this assumption.

A spool of a test run in SQL*Plus is as follows:

```
SQL> 
SQL> select count(1)
  2  from user_indexes
  3  where table_name = 'TECH_VALUES'
  4  ;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         0

SQL> 
SQL> select count(1)
  2  from user_constraints
  3  where table_name = 'TECH_VALUES'
  4      and constraint_type != 'C'
  5  ;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         0

SQL> 
SQL> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.

SQL> alter system flush shared_pool;

System altered.

SQL> 
SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
08.06.14 23:18:40,053000 +02:00

SQL> 
SQL> select tech_type, count(1)
  2  from tech_values
  3  where parent_group_id != 0
  4  group by rollup(tech_type);

T   COUNT(1)
- ----------
A      20048
B      39984
C      19984
       80016

SQL> 
SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
08.06.14 23:18:40,144000 +02:00

SQL> 
SQL> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.

SQL> alter system flush shared_pool;

System altered.

SQL> 
SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
08.06.14 23:18:40,246000 +02:00

SQL> 
SQL> with xyz as (
  2      select connect_by_root(link_id) as root_link_id, connect_by_root(group_id) as root_group_id, tech_type
  3      from tech_values X
  4      start with parent_group_id = 0
  5      connect by prior group_id = parent_group_id
  6  )
  7  select *
  8  from xyz pivot (
  9          count(1) as tech_type
 10          for tech_type in (
 11          'A' as A,
 12          'B' as B,
 13          'C' as C
 14          ));

ROOT_LINK_ID                                                     ROOT_GROUP_ID A_TECH_TYPE B_TECH_TYPE C_TECH_TYPE
---------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
LETTER_B                                                                  1800        3667        7482        3854
LETTER_B                                                                   200        3712        7583        3708
LETTER_C                                                                   300        6326       12450        6229
LETTER_A                                                                   100        6343       12469        6193

SQL> 
SQL> select *
  2  from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor())
  3  ;

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  59hmrtw6q3f4u, child number 0
-------------------------------------
with xyz as (     select connect_by_root(link_id) as root_link_id,
connect_by_root(group_id) as root_group_id, tech_type     from
tech_values X     start with parent_group_id = 0     connect by prior
group_id = parent_group_id ) select * from xyz pivot (         count(1)
as tech_type         for tech_type in (             'A' as A,
  'B' as B,             'C' as C         ))

Plan hash value: 3833790953

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |             |       |       |   563 (100)|          |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY PIVOT        |             | 29102 |  1420K|   563   (1)| 01:23:35 |
|   2 |   VIEW                      |             | 29102 |  1420K|  1044  (47)| 02:35:00 |
|*  3 |    CONNECT BY WITH FILTERING|             |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL       | TECH_VALUES |     4 |    84 |   187   (0)| 00:27:46 |
|*  5 |     HASH JOIN               |             | 29098 |   966K|   375   (1)| 00:55:41 |
|   6 |      CONNECT BY PUMP        |             |       |       |            |          |
|   7 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TECH_VALUES | 80020 |  1641K|   187   (0)| 00:27:46 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("PARENT_GROUP_ID"=PRIOR NULL)
   4 - filter("PARENT_GROUP_ID"=0)
   5 - access("connect$_by$_pump$_002"."prior group_id "="PARENT_GROUP_ID")


31 rows selected.

SQL> 
SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
08.06.14 23:18:40,805000 +02:00

SQL> 
SQL> spool off
```

Comment: I will give it a try - thanks. Just want to bring to your attention that I updated my thread above to mention that duplicate parent link ids are also possible as shown for the two LETTER_B entries together with their children but for different GROUP IDs. Q1) Will your query cater for these duplicate entries as I need to process these two duplicates or any other duplicate parent link ids as separate records and not group the technology counts as just one LETTER_B record? Q2) With the pivot, can I access each individual Tech Type A, Tech Type B and Tech Type C column values for each link id?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, using the above data returned from your query, how would I go about updating my other table LINK_COUNTS as part of your query, i.e. update link_counts set (LINK_ID,TECH_TYPE_A,TECH_TYPE_B,TECH_TYPE_C) = (with xyz .....) etc ?

Comment: Hi Tonsils.

Answer to Q1:
No. Too bad you did not specify your question correctly the first time. I already deleted the test environment, now I have to recreate it from scratch.

Answer to Q2:
I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. Clearly, the select queries all three tech types, so if you need just one tech type, then select just one.

Answer to the 3rd question:
See the updated answer. However, please specify how shall the update act when there are duplicate root link_ids. Shall it overwrite the values in the link_counts table ? Or shall it sum up the tech type counts ? Or ... ?

Comment: Apologies nop77svk that I didn't specify the possibility of duplicates  in my original thread but only realised this after doing more thorough testing. I am really keen to use your solution but just need to work out how to also cater for duplicate link ids. Thanks for your solution on Q3. With the updating of duplicate root link ids within the LINK_COUNTS table, the actual duplicate LINK_IDs will already exist within this table against a different ID and the LINK_COUNTS table also holds the same GROUP_ID at parent level only as in the TECH_VALUES table. See updated thread for this column.

Comment: nop77svk - hopefully have updated thread/comments to answer all your questions.

Comment: Thanks nop77svk - will have a try with it now. If you don't mind, pls to not delete your TEST environment just yet. From checking your solution, you have also included to cater for the update as well for these duplicates. I think I am correct on this. Thanks.

Comment: Hey nop77svk - your updated solution to include duplicates has worked perfectly. Exactly what I was after. FYI, I will not be able to test the update/merge until mid next week but will definitely come back to you. Really appreciate your help - great work. Thanks.

Comment: Hey nop77svk - just a query with what you wrote above, i.e. "On a test set of 39000 records it took an Intel Core i5 with Oracle 11.2 (and flushed buffer cache) approx 0.15 sec to compute this." Are you able to let me know what indexes you used on your test case as I find running my version on say 1000 records, takes about 1 min 30 secs? Thanks.

Comment: Primary key (id), unique index (group_id), foreign key (parent_group_id) references self (group_id).

But that does not matter. Even if I drop all of the indexes and constraints, the query runs in 0.25 s (for 80000 records now). See the updated answer for a SQL*Plus spool, check out the systimestamp selects and see for yourself what the times are. The execution plan is attached there as well.