# How to assign the Parent Group IDs to each record of a hierarchical table in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, view, oracle11g, hierarchy

Based on the following sample hierarchical data that exists within the TECH_VALUES table, how can I create a view, say TECH_VALUES_VW that will take this same data but have an additional column, namely GROUP_ID_PARENT that will show the group id where the parent group id is 0 against the row that child belongs to, see new column data sample:

```
ID      GROUP_ID      LINK_ID      PARENT_GROUP_ID      TECH_TYPE  GROUP_ID_PARENT
------- ------------- ------------ -------------------- ---------- --------------- 
1       100           LETTER_A     0                               100
2       200           LETTER_B     0                               200
3       300           LETTER_C     0                               300
4       400           LETTER_A1    100                  A          100               
5       500           LETTER_A2    100                  A          100               
6       600           LETTER_A3    100                  A          100               
7       700           LETTER_AA1   400                  B          100              
8       800           LETTER_AAA1  700                  C          100             
9       900           LETTER_B2    200                  B          200               
10      1000          LETTER_BB5   900                  B          200              
12      1200          LETTER_CC1   300                  C          300
13      1300          LETTER_CC2   300                  C          300
14      1400          LETTER_CC3   300                  A          300
15      1500          LETTER_CCC5  1400                 A          300
16      1600          LETTER_CCC6  1500                 C          300
17      1700          LETTER_BBB8  900                  B          200
18      1800          LETTER_B     0                               1800
19      1900          LETTER_B2    1800                 B          1800               
20      2000          LETTER_BB5   1900                 B          1800              
21      2100          LETTER_BBB8  1900                 B          1800
```

So based on the above, I want to take the table definition:

```
Table Name: TECH_VALUES:
    ID,
    GROUP_ID,
    LINK_ID
    PARENT_GROUP_ID,
    TECH_TYPE
```

and create a new view

```
View Name: TECH_VALUES_VW:
        ID,
        GROUP_ID,
        LINK_ID
        PARENT_GROUP_ID,
        TECH_TYPE,
        GROUP_ID_PARENT
```

based on the above sample data from the TECH_VALUES table.

I am looking to create a new query to build this new view which will only use the GROUP_IDs for the PARENT_GROUP_IDs that are 0 for each row.

### Updated

Just to make things a whole lot clearer of exactly what I am after is if I take out only the records where the PARENT_GROUP_ID is 0 within the TECH_VALUES table, i.e.

```
ID      GROUP_ID      LINK_ID      PARENT_GROUP_ID     
------- ------------- ------------ --------------------
1       100           LETTER_A     0                   
2       200           LETTER_B     0                   
3       300           LETTER_C     0                   
18      1800          LETTER_B     0
```

Using just the GROUP_ID values for these 4 records, assign this GROUP_ID to all of the children records for each of these parent link ids as a new column in the TECH_VALUES_VW as well as to the original link ids (where PARENT_GROUP_ID is 0) as shown in the sample data set above.

Comment: This is not clear.  I understand what you want when the parent group id is 0, but not when it is something else.

Comment: Dan, pls see my update to my original thread - hopefully it is much clearer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Perform Counts on a Oracle Hierarchical Table based on Parent Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042104/how-to-perform-counts-on-a-oracle-hierarchical-table-based-on-parent-link)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then this might be what you're after:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tech_values_vw
AS
SELECT TV.*,
    CASE WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN group_id ELSE connect_by_root(group_id) END AS group_id_parent
FROM tech_values TV
START WITH parent_group_id = 0
CONNECT BY PRIOR group_id = parent_group_id
;
```